# Heavy regex editing - rearanging lines and a few modifications

Tags: regex, notepad++

So i'm trying to turn this:

```
Line 1: Goal = 23
10+5=15 
15+8=23

Line 2: Goal = 57
4×10=40
40+5=45
6×2=12
45+12=57

......

Line 1000: Goal = 200
12-10=2
50x2=100
100x2=200
```

Into this:

```
Line 1: (Goal = 23) 10+5=15 | 15+8=23
Line 2: (Goal = 57) 4×10=40 | 40+5=45 | 6×2=12 | 45+12=57

......

Line 1000: (Goal = 200) 12-10=2 | 50x2=100 | 100x2=200
```

The end result will have 1000 lines, and doing this manually is time consuming... I need to make a few more modifications, but i'll manage to do them on my own after everything is on the same line.
My regex skills are really basic, and i can't figure out how to do this on my own.

Comment: Ok so i managed to do it on my own, probably not the best way, but it did the job.
Used \s* \s* to put the lines on the same line, and the rest with simple find and replace, and some column select (ALT key) and then paste the things i needed...

Comment: Put that in an answer of your own, then. (That's about what I would have recommended in any case.)

Comment: M42's answer works as well, and is cleaner than mine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you want but close:

Find what: `\R(\d+)`
Replace with: `| $1`

Comment: this works as well, i had to insert some things to make it work with \s* \s*